# How to keep react-pro-sidebar submenus open when routing happened in react-pro-sidebar?

Tags: reactjs, sidebar

I am using react-pro-sidebar. Menu hierarchy works as expected.

When I click all its submenus are shown. In the submenus I have routing. So when I click anyone of the submenus, all the whole menus are getting collapsed. Looks its due to routing. Is it? If yes, How can prevent this?

i wants to expanded my submenu whenever i clicked on submenu

```
<ProSidebar collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <Menu iconShape="square">
          {/* LOGO AND MENU ICON */}
          <MenuItem
            onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
            icon={isCollapsed ? <MenuOutlinedIcon /> : undefined}
            style={{
              margin: "10px 0 20px 0",
              color: colors.grey[100],
            }}
          >
            {!isCollapsed && (
              <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
                ml="15px"
              >
                <Typography variant="h3" color={colors.grey[100]}>
                  SimpliTaught
                </Typography>
                <IconButton onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
                  <MenuOutlinedIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            )}
          </MenuItem>

          {/* {!isCollapsed && (
            <Box mb="25px">
              <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <img
                  alt="profile-user"
                  width="100px"
                  height="100px"
                  src={`https://picsum.photos/id/6/200/300`}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", borderRadius: "50%" }}
                />
                <span style={{ position: "absolute", right: "0", left: "0" }}>
                  <CreateOutlinedIcon />
                </span>
              </Box>
              <Box textAlign="center">
                <Typography
                  variant="h2"
                  color={colors.grey[100]}
                  fontWeight="bold"
                  sx={{ m: "10px 0 0 0" }}
                >
                  Shoaib Qasim
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" color={colors.greenAccent[500]}>
                  Super Admin
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          )} */}

          <Box paddingLeft={isCollapsed ? undefined : "10%"}>
            {!isCollapsed && (
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                color={colors.grey[300]}
                sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
              >
                User Management
              </Typography>
            )}
            <Item
              title="Dashboard"
              to="/dashboard"
              icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <SubMenu
              title="Users"
              icon={<PeopleOutlineIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
              style={{
                color: colors.grey[100],
              }}
            >
              <Item
                title="Users List"
                to="/user-list"
                icon={<PermIdentityOutlinedIcon />}
                selected={selected}
                setSelected={setSelected}
              />
            </SubMenu>

            {!isCollapsed && (
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                color={colors.grey[300]}
                sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
              >
                Manage Content
              </Typography>
            )}
            <Item
              title="Add User"
              to="/add-user"
              icon={<CategoryIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Books"
              to="/book-list"
              icon={<ContactsOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Top Courses"
              to="/top-courses"
              icon={<ReceiptOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Pages
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Profile Form"
              to="/form"
              icon={<PersonOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Calendar"
              to="/calendar"
              icon={<CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
          </Box>
        </Menu>
      </ProSidebar>
```

Comment: <Item/> is my other component in which i am using Menuitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a codesandbox here that does it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pro-sidebar-with-nesting-and-routing-and-submenu-not-collapsing-f3q27b

You don't have your routing code so I don't know how you are doing your routing, but following the tutorial of react-router-dom and using the Outlet component, you will be able to achieve this.

But you could also get the current path of your page and use that by actively controlling the Submenu component with the DefaultOpen property.

```
const { pathname: currentPath } = useLocation()

<SubMenu
    label="Contacts"
    defaultOpen={currentPath.startsWith("/contacts")}
    icon={<i className="ti-layout-grid2"></i>}
>
        <MenuItem
            active={currentPath === "/contacts/isa"}
            component={<Link to="/contacts/isa" />}
        >
            Isa
        </MenuItem>
</SubMenu>
```